# no launchable updates found in database. --expo-go

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-eas

I'm trying to run my app on **expo-go** but when I run the app it loads but I get an error.
"There was a problem running **app name**", then it asks me to try again.
below this there's another error message. "no launchable updates found in database."

Does anyone have a fix for this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Locate your app.json file look for **"runtimeVersion"**, if you have a runtimeVersion, pass this **"exposdk:44.0.0"** as the runtimeVersion value.

it should look like so:

`"runtimeVersion": "exposdk:44.0.0",`

Note: using expo sdk 44.0.0 at the time of this publish.

Edit: When building your app with EAS or "expo publish --release-channel" this will display an error that the runtimeVersion value is not valid. But because expo caches the runtimeValue you can simply change this back to "2.718" or whichever value you provided, and this should fix the bug at build time.

Comment: Thank you! :) I had added `runtimeVersion` for the sake of the EAS build and that caused the issue.

Comment: For sure man, no problem.

Comment: resolved it also for me. Thank you man!

Comment: For development proposes, using Expo Go, by commenting the `runtimeVersion` attribute also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For development proposes, using Expo Go, by commenting the

> runtimeVersion

attribute also worked for me